# VS Code not providing suggestions for imports (Next JS, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, next.js, eslint

I've spent the last hour trying to get this working and I can't find a solution. I have a component at ./components/layout/Layout.js.

I'm using this component in ./pages/_app.js. However, while eslint sees that I haven't imported it, it doesn't offer a suggestion to autoimport it (in the quick fix menu). I would like to be able to click quick fix and see the suggested import, as I get in Typescript projects (if this is even possible with JS.)

Here is my jsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["./components/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and this is my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    commonjs: true,
    node: true,
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  globals: {},
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'import', 'react-hooks'],
  ignorePatterns: ['node_modules/'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [['components', './components']]
      }
    },
    react: {
      version: 'latest' // "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
    }
  }
};
```

It would be really great if someone could offer some suggestions for the configs here. As I've said, I've trawled through Google for a long time and haven't been able to get it working.

Many thanks

Comment: Only my guess. Two things to try out. (1) try use the `include` or `files` option in `jsconfig.json` (2) add `// @ts-check` at the beginning of both files.

Comment: @hackape thanks, I'll try

Comment: On top of that, there’s also another idea worth trying. Use `tsconfig.json` instead and turn on `allowJs: true` to fool the editor to believe this is a TS project.

Comment: ok thank you - I'll give it a go, though surely there's a vanilla js solution to this...

Comment: I spend most of the time dealing with TS projects. Some facts that back up my educated guess. vscode uses TS engine under the hood to support pure JS project. TS by design will crunch all named symbols in the project and store them inside an internal lookup table, this is how the “suggested import” quick fix work. So you need to tell the engine what files to look into.

Comment: That is extremely helpful to know, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update tsconfig.json

add either

```
"checkJs": true
```

or

```
"allowJs": true
```

under **compilerOption** in tsconfig.json to get the suggetions in.

post update just reload the vs code

Comment: Not exactly sure why but in a nextjs ts proj it was not showing the auto import suggestions, so I added `checkJs: true` in the root `tsconfig.json` file and a reload.  Then it starts to work as it should. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

To enable VSCode auto imports you need the following setting inside compiler options:

```
"checkJs": true
```

Comment: This is part of the solution that allowed VS Code to present **Add import..** fixes for me. I also had to add **@types/react** via my package manager (pnpm) in order to prevent linting errors that showed on any Next.js **Head** components in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this, it work at 2023

```
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).